# My current loop which i use to sort elements by their digits produces an list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, indexing

Im a complete noob and this is Part of my first sorting algorithm(Radixsort)

So far this way of sorting the numbers by their respective digits is working out but i still get an list index out of range. My theorie is that the while loop takes an extra iteration but i dont understand why.

```
def put_into_bucket(liste, iteration):
iteration = int

digit = len(liste[0]) - 1
i = 0

while i < len(liste):
    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 0:
        zero.append(liste[i])
        print(zero)

    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 1:
        one.append(liste[i])
        print(one)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 2:
        two.append(liste[i])
        print(two)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 3:
        three.append(liste[i])
        print(three)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 4:
        four.append(liste[i])
        print(four)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 5:
        five.append(liste[i])
        print(five)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 6:
        six.append(liste[i])
        print(six)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 7:
        seven.append(liste[i])
        print(seven)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 8:
        eight.append(liste[i])
        print(eight)


    if int(liste[i][digit]) == 9:
        nine.append(liste[i])
        print(nine)
    i = i + 1

    print(sorted_array)
```

put_into_bucket(liste=['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006'], iteration=0)

Comment: Please tag with the language. python perhaps? Your index starts at `i=0` but you test `while i<=len`. That should be `while i<len`. Also, consider `if ... elif ... elif ...` instead of `if ... if ... if ...`

Comment: Thanks for the the comment ! I tried replacing the if with elifs but and also the <= with <. Now i wont get the index out of range but the output is doubled

Answer (score 0):

As [jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681675/my-current-loop-which-i-use-to-sort-elements-by-their-digits-produces-an-list-in/54681728?noredirect=1#comment96152423_54681675) mentioned, one problem is the bounds check in the `while` statement. It should be

```
while i < len(liste)
```

I still think the increment should be out side the if checks, but you say in the comments that moving it there doubles your output. Since this is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't help you with that.

Put the increment outside the `if` statements. After a successful `if` check, the next `if` statement is attempting to use `i`, which may no longer be valid.

**Example**

```
x = 1
if True:
    x += 1
if True:
    x += 1
print(x)
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Your other option is to put `continue` statements at the end of each `if` block, but you should really move the increment out of the `if` checks because then you only do it in one place.

Comment: Thanks alot ! This defenetly solved part of my problem.

Comment: Is it wrong if i put just one increment at the end of the statements? Because now i get everything doubled

Comment: The increment should be after all the `if` statements, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Ok thanks ! Im sorry if my grammar is bad im not a native english speaker. 
But do you have any idea why i now get a doubled result for example: if i input =['0001', '0002', '0003'] the output is ['0001','0001, '0002',0002','0003,'0003']
Im sorry if this is a bad question ^^"

Comment: Your grammar is fine, but I can't answer your question about the doubling because you haven't put your complete program in your question. This means I don't have all the information I need.

Comment: I updated it to the full method should i also add the console output ?

Comment: You need to create a stand-alone program that can reproduce the problem and include sample data and expected output.